# Unable to Load a document into Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

We are using docusign for more than 3 years, We have several demo accounts as well as we have paid account too.

we are using the following docusign rest service

https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/*****/envelopes

In our local environment we are using the above demo rest service, Till last month (August) we were able to post the document into docusign without any issues. The Problem now is that we are not able to post a document to docusign.

we getting the exception like

```
"errorCode": "UNABLE_TO_LOAD_DOCUMENT",  "message": "Unable to load the document. Unable to load Document(1;CONSENT FORM). Error: Cannot add the widget (connected to field: ColombiaCurrentlyresideYes) to page -1, because it's already added to page -1. If you want to re-use this widget, please remove it from the current page first
```

Same data worked till last month (August) and it's working fine now in docusign production account(paid). we are not sure what went wrong in demo accounts. Any release are done in demo accounts?
I tired using the same template in web console too, same error throws in browser console
[image]

Please help me to resolve this issues.

We require your guidance regarding this issue!

Comment: Please post your raw API request that causes this error so we can diagnose/debug

Comment: Thanks @Ergin .Stack-overflow body characters limit is 30000, our raw data exceeds the limit.So Please suggest some idea to share the request?

Comment: What we really need is your envelope definition, especially the `documents` node and related data.  Please post your envelope body (you can redact any private or personal info if needed)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest first trying to load the documents into an envelope by using the DocuSign Web tool (NDSE). If that doesn't work then the document is the issue.

Has the document changed?

**Re changes:** Yes, the demo system is changed each month. Then the changes are applied to the production systems. While we do have thousands of automatic regression tests, problem can creep through the system.

I suggest you contact DocuSign customer support to give them the document which is failing to load.

Comment: Thanks @Larry. No, Document haven't changed.I tried using the template in Docusign Web Console it throwing the same error in browser console.I attached the error images in my post.

Comment: Hi @SuriyaadevanBalu -- it is good news that your document triggers the problem when it is uploaded. It means that the problem is clearly the processing of your specific document. Please contact DocuSign customer support, provide them with the document, and just talk with them about how it can't be loaded into the DocuSign web tool template screen. Don't even mention your API application--it is immaterial to the root issue.